# Populate Sugar ORM objects with a json file

Tags: android, json, sugarorm

I'm trying to get JSON data into Sugar ORM objects, so that I can use these without having to get JSON data from a server. I'll just simply download a zipfile (wich contains a JSON file) and unzip it so that it is ready for use. Whenever I update the JSON data, I'd just dowload the new zip file and replace the old JSON data.

An example of my JSON file could be:

```
{
"id": "1",
"title": "JsonTitle",
"location": {
"city": "RightHere",
"street": "OnTheCorner",
"type": "Road"
}
```

My model class would look like this:

```
public class Example extends SugarRecord {
//setters and getters

}
```

How would I populate the Sugar ORM objects with this JSON data?

Comment: Start by adding some properties to your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to serialize json to Java Object.

To do that you have multiple solutions:

- JSONObject Class (Android only)
- Gson Library (from Google) : https://github.com/google/gson
- Jackson Library : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

You can find samples on the main pages of these projects.